# Access Login view controller when pressing Log Out button

Tags: xcode, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have an app using a tab bar and, when the app loads, I expose a login view controller to authenticate the user:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

initialScreenViewController = [[Login alloc] init];
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[window addSubview:initialScreenViewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

When the user successfully authenticates, I hide the login view to expose the tab bar view:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

My question is this....I have a log out button in the app.  When that button is pressed, how do I essentially expose the login screen again and block the tab view?

Thank you!
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you did the first time:

```
initialScreenViewController = [[Login alloc] init];
[window addSubview:initialScreenViewController.view];
```

Although it might be a little more straightforward to use `presentModalViewController:animated:` to display it on top of the tab bar controller.

Comment: Thank you for that!  I don't know much about using the modal view but I will look into it!

Comment: Ok, so now my code looks like:  `[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
 [window makeKeyAndVisible];
 return YES;
 
 [self presentModalViewController: Login animated:YES];` but I'm getting an error 'Expected expression before 'Login'.  Login is the name of my view controller.  Any ideas?  Thank you!!!

Comment: `Login` is the name of the class. You need to create a variable with an instance, something like `Login *loginInstance = [[Login alloc] init]; [self presentModalViewController: loginInstance animated:YES];`

Comment: Makes total sense - thanks!  I fixed that and the program compiled with no issue.  However, when I run it, it goes straight to the tab bar view and the login view doesn't come up in front?  My code in the didFinishLaunching portion of the AppDelegate is:  `[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
 [window makeKeyAndVisible];
 return YES; 
 Login *loginInstance = [[Login alloc] init];
 [self presentModalViewController: loginInstance animated:YES];`  I REALLY appreciate your help!

Comment: Two problems there. First, everything after `return YES;` is not executed because you have returned from the function. Second, this is in your AppDelegate, but a UIApplicationDelegate does not respond to `presentModalViewController:animated:`. Try `[tabBarController presentModalViewController:loginInstance animated:NO]` instead.

Comment: Sorry - can I ask one more question...?  Within my tab controller, I have 4 tabs.  The "Logout" button for my app lives on the 4th tab.  When I click Logout, it works perfectly with:   `Login *loginInstance = [[Login alloc] init];
 [self presentModalViewController:loginInstance animated:YES];`  Then, I login in again and the login screen slides away just like I would expect.  Problem is that it puts me back to the 4th tab which makes sense. Is there a way to have it go to the first tab upon login?  Right now, this is all I'm doing after login:  `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];`

Comment: UITabBarController has methods `setSelectedIndex:` and `setSelectedViewController:` that you can use to change the current tab by index number or by the corresponding view controller.

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry if this is a stupid question - but do I need to redeclare the tabBarController in my login implementation file (the tab bar controller is currently in the AppDelegate).  When I add `[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]` to my login implementation, I get undeclared variable.  I can redeclare tabBarController but just didn't know if that was bad/the wrong way to do it?  Thanks again - I only started working with XCode/Obj C yesterday so you've been a huge help!!

Comment: You can access your app delegate from anywhere using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`; you'll probably need to cast it to the appropriate class before you can access its properties. Then make a `@property` to access the tabBarController ivar and you should be good.

Comment: Awesome that worked.  Just have one strange thing going on...I have 4 tabs, if I set the selectedIndex to 1 or 2, the view goes to tab 2.  If I set to 3 it goes to 3 and if I set to 4, it goes to 4.  I can't figure out why selectedIndex:1 is going to the second tab?

Comment: I think I got it - I had to go into IB and set a tag value for each button.  Seems to work now!  Thanks again for all the help!